# POSTMAN jetpacks TESTING within for loop

Tags: rest, testing, automated-tests, postman

Hitting API w/ GET request, checking if item has been deleted by globals.id variable, have test inside forloop and when I run test returns 0/0 tests passed. All of my console logs within the for loop work, the objects contain values matching what I have as well. Anyone know how to do this?

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);


for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  tests["id has been deleted"] = data[i].id !== globals.id;
  if(data[i].id !== globalID){
    tests["id has been deleted"] = data[i].id !== globals.id;
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: ?? How do I get my "tests["id has been deleted"] = data[i].id !== globals.id to actually run. Postman is completely ignoring it. :(

Answer (score 7):

I could make test with for loop.
My Json:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": "2804",
      "title": "Some title",
      ...
    },
    ...
  ],
  "total": "2788"
}
```

My test:

```
for (var i in data.rows){
    var obj = data.rows[i];
    tests["title of row #" + i + " is not null"] = !!obj.title;
    tests["title of row #" + i + " is not empty"] = obj.title !== "";
}
```

But if I use "return true" Postman shows "Tests (0/0)"

Comment: is there any way we can exit loop when some condition is true. Like we use break to exit from loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `forEach` loop for iterating the result set returned in response. It returns the objects of specified type which can be used for processing.

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody); 
data.forEach(function(process){
    var processId = "Id" + process.id;
    //console.log("processId" + processId);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

*Yes Ranson Namba!  I'm experiencing the same thing - even attempting to write to the console is ignored within my For loops.  What's more, it would be ever so helpful to be able to specify arrays within the For loop, but apparently Postman doesn't allow that either.  What's the solution to all this limiting BS?*

```
var responseData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
for (i = 0; i < responseData.scoringResults.length; i++) {
  var scores =  responseData[i].score;
  for (j; j < scores.length; j++){ //scores.length = 4 at this point
    var scoreValues = scores[j].split(",");
    tests["Verify number of score dimensions"] = scoreValues.length === 4;
  }
}
tests["Status code is 200"] = responseCode.code === 200;
```

*The last tests works fine, just nothing you put inside either for loop works, even a simple console.log("whatever").  A little help?  Thx*

Comment: not an answer to the question - please comment in the comment section